# Loading AssetBundle from URL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm trying to load assetbundle form server.

My assetbunles is live on URL. Right now my game in editor on webgl platform.

My load assetbundles script:

```
[Obsolete]
IEnumerator Start()
{
    while (!Caching.ready)
        yield return null;

    using (var www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("http://dev71.onlinetestingserver.com/assetBundles/cube", 5))
    {
        yield return www;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
            yield return null;
        }
        var myLoadedAssetBundle = www.assetBundle;
        var asset = myLoadedAssetBundle.mainAsset;
        Instantiate(www.assetBundle.LoadAsset("cube"));
    }
}
```

but it gives error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   LoadAssetBundles+d__0.MoveNext () (at Assets/LoadAssetBundles.cs:76)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)

I just want that when I play my game, it loads asset bundle perfectly.
I already created asset bundles.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking that for null.

```
using (var www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("http://dev71.onlinetestingserver.com/assetBundles/cube", 5))
{
    yield return www;  <--- www MIGHT BE NULL
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
        yield return null;
    }
    var myLoadedAssetBundle = www.assetBundle; 

    var asset = myLoadedAssetBundle.mainAsset; <--- www.assetBundle MIGHT BE NULL
    Instantiate(www.assetBundle.LoadAsset("cube"));
}
```

Comment: what's the solution of this?

Comment: Depends on how you want to handle errors.   First thing I would do is confirm that is actually the problem.  Put breakpoints on the code I've highlighted and see where the problem is, then you can decide how you want to handle it.